# Python Error after filtering on NoneType - TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python

Error Message is :

```
File "/workspace/explanation.py", line 231, in function~~~
    while 'error' in returnVal:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

And my code is :

```
#function(~~~) : Get DictionaryType value from server
#Occasionally, the server may return NoneType
returnVal = function(~~~)
if returnVal is not None:
   while 'error' in returnVal:
      ....
```

I used a conditional statement to filter out None, but I don't know why it's called NoneType Error in the next sentence.
Why do I get errors in my code?
please help...

*
The error does not appear from the beginning of the loop, but occurs suddenly when the program operates normally and a considerable amount of time has passed.
And, since the entire code of my program proceeds sequentially, the value cannot be changed in the middle. So it's very frustrating.

Comment: What is the function's definition?

Comment: Does your loop makes it's first iteration ? I am guessing you are modifying the value of returnVal  somewhere in the loop, maybe that's where it gets the NoneType. Please post the code of your function and the full loop

Comment: @CharlyRoch Thanks. I also think it may be. The error does not appear from the beginning of the loop, but occurs suddenly when the program operates normally and a considerable amount of time has passed.
However, since the entire code of my program proceeds sequentially, the value cannot be changed in the middle. So it's very frustrating.

Comment: What is returnVal  type ? you can use "in" for lists, tuples, dict, and containers kind of variables. You check if returnVal is None but not if it contains None ... it is not clear without a working example and data, see [mre]

Comment: @Malo Thanks. Something is starting to appear. So you mean, the tuple could be None, but the tuple value exists but contains only None, so that error can occur?

Comment: @STanP it seems somewhere inside the while loop you change the returnVal value to None. Which causes the error message, because 'error' in None is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should change like this:

```py
while returnVal and 'error' in returnVal:
   ...
```

This way, you ensure that `returnVal` evaluates to `True` (so no None values)

Comment: thank you. I didn't know this. I'll test it and come back

Comment: this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a `while` condition gets checked multiple times. As mentioned in @CharlyRoch's comment, the body of your loop (which you don't show us) must contain `returnVal = None` at some point. The solution is to make sure you don't assign `None` to `returnVal` and make sure it continues to refer to some iterable.

Comment: thank you. Let's try it right now.